# Copy columns from different sheets into master sheet in VBA with 1 fixed column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a comparison of offers received from all partners. I have made one workbook where the offers from all partners are added in different sheets. Here, the 1st column is the same for all suppliers viz. the product details. The offer comparison sheet viz. Master sheet should display the offers of all partners.

eg. Column A values in all the sheets of the workbook (Master sheet as well as other sheets) is the same. Column "B, C...n" in Master sheet are blank, while all other sheets have some values in Column B. I need a macro to copy values from Sheet 1.Column B and paste it (paste special) in Master.Column B. Similarly, values from Sheet 2.Column B is to be pasted in Master.Column C and should be repeated for all other sheets in the workbook (Sheets 3, 4....n) into Master.Column (D,E..n).

I tried the following code:

```
Sub Summary()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets              
     If ws.Name <> "Master" Then
          ws.Range("C2:C10").Copy                                                  
          Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues                            
     End If        
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

However, the output here gets pasted one below the other in the same column instead of in the next adjacent columns.

[image: Output image - stacked]

It is required in corresponding adjacent columns.

Hope I am clear in explaining the requirement. Pls let me know how to get the Column B of "n" sheets in adjacent columns in the Master sheet.

In case it can be done without using the above codes, it is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Sub Summary()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim EmptyCol As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Master" Then
        ws.Range("B2:B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy '<-- copy all values in column B
        With Sheets("Master")
            EmptyCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            .Range(.Cells(1, EmptyCol), .Cells(1, EmptyCol)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what we've got the `INDIRECT` function for. Say sheet2 contains this:

[image]

and similarly, Sheet3 has `4,5,6` and Sheet4 has `7,8,9` then we can get all of those values like this:

[image]

...with an `INDIRECT` formula. Place this in B2 and drag down/across

```
=INDIRECT(B$1&"!" & ADDRESS($A2,1))
```

Have a play around and let me know if you can't get it working in your setup

Comment: I need to have a dynamic comparison of data as the no of partner sheets would change all the time. So looking for a macro based solution. Have noted this solution as well. Thanks!